# Running commands without waiting page completely load with Selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a automation with Selenium, and i want to run some commands after open the link but no waiting for load the page, i want to run this codes even the page is not completely load, or while the page is loading

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\Gabri\anaconda3\chromedriver.exe")
wait: WebDriverWait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com/')

# I want to run some commands in this lines, without wait the page load
...


# I did this wait just for print when the page completely load
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                                           'body > header > div > div.-main.flex--item > a.-logo.js-gps-track > span')))

print('The page is completely load')
driver.quit()
```

> The commands that i want to run in `...` no have relation with the page, that is why i need run without wait the page load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to run these methods without waiting for the page loaded is to run them before involving the `driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com/')` method

Comment: I know, but is no possible add a option in ```driver = webdriver.Chrome(path, option)``` or something like this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with such options.